# How to stop running tests if a specific test fails?

Tags: phpunit

I know there is an option in PHPUnit to `stop-on-failure` but I don't want it to stop when *any* test fails, just when this specific test fails.

For example, in my `setUp` I connect to a DB, and in the first test I check if it connected to the correct DB. If that fails, I can't run the rest of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@depends` feature of PHP.

If a test depends on another, it will only be executed if that other test succeeded. Otherwise it will be skipped. This allows you to pinpoint problems better.

Usage: Add a PHPDOC block at the top of the test function that should only be executed when the other test is successful, and add a line `@depends testConnectToDb`.

See http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.depends and http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies for some more details.

Comment: That's good, but then I need to add one of those to every single method except the first? Is that the only way?

Comment: You can also use the `assertPreCondition` (and `assertPostCondition`) functions in PHPUnit to run assertions before (or after) the test function. You can also mark tests as skipped in `setUp` if the connection fails, so you need not check it with a test (I recommend adding an explanation test to every case of skipping to make it clear WHY the test is skipped).